# CoC-clangd for .m files

Tags: objective-c, coc.nvim, clangd

I want to contribute to a project which uses objc heavily. As I am not a mac user I cannot use Xcode for this project. So I looked for solutions and found that vim has a code completion plugin (CoC) which should support objc via CoC-clangd. I think that I got it working for some files. But when I open files with .m extension (method files for objc) the coc-clangd does not start.

Is there something I can do to make it work? Is there another alternative or workaround?

Comment: What's the filetype of your m file? Check it from `:verbose set filetype?`, coc-clangd can work for objective-c.

Comment: It say that the filetype is murphi. which is something I've never heard of :D Any idea how to change that?

Comment: Try `set filetype=objc`

Comment: that has worked for the file, but i would have to set it globaly somehow. However, I figured that vsc has a clangd extension which seems to work well. which is awesome

Comment: The key problem is your vim make .m filetype error, coc-clangd will work for c/cpp/objc files automatically, without any configurations.